# HANA: I created a view from a single table. After creating the view i want to modify the column of a view from VARCHAR[10] to INTEGER[10]. How to do?

Tags: database, database-design, database-administration, hana

SAP HANA: I created a view from a single table. After creating the view i want to modify the column of a view from VARCHAR[10] to INTEGER[10].

I performed the following SQL queries. But to no avail.

The SQL Queries are as follows:

```
ALTER VIEW ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_USER_SETUP MODIFY COLUMN EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER;

ALTER VIEW ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_USER_SETUP MODIFY EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER;

ALTER VIEW ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_USER_SETUP ALTER COLUMN EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER;

ALTER VIEW ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_USER_SETUP ALTER EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER;
```

Require help in this. How to alter the column of a view IN SAP HANA

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of columns in SQL views in inherited from the defining select statement. As an example this view will return one column with type `NVARCHAR(1)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST AS 
SELECT '1' AS COL1 
FROM DUMMY
```

You need to change the datatype in the underlying select statement to change the output of the view to make `COL1` integer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST AS 
SELECT CAST('1' AS INTEGER) AS COL1 
FROM DUMMY
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try by dropping the data? If that did not work, then you need drop the table and recreate it.

Comment: This should be a comment under the original question, it isn't an anwer